# how to pass class object as parameter in restful service method?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I want to pass object in restful service method as a parameter. Following is the Interface code.

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    UriTemplate = "searchCMSExposure/{requestObject}")]
        ResponseObject<GenericCollection<CONT_EXPRInfo>> SearchCMSExposure(RequestObject<ProposalInfoParm> requestObject);
```

As expectedly I got error **Operation 'SearchCMSExposure' in contract 'IProposalService' has a path variable named 'requestObject' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.** as it's need to string type. How can I pass object as parameter in restful service method?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
     using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
    using System.ServiceModel.Description;
  public class StackOverflow_6783264
{
 public class InputData
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITest
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/InsertData?param1={param1}")]
    string saveDataGet(InputData param1);
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/InsertData")]
    string saveDataPost(InputData param1);
}
public class Service : ITest
{
    public string saveDataGet(InputData param1)
    {
        return "Via GET: " + param1.FirstName + " " + param1.LastName;
    }
    public string saveDataPost(InputData param1)
    {
        return "Via POST: " + param1.FirstName + " " + param1.LastName;
    }
}
public class MyQueryStringConverter : QueryStringConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
    {
        return (type == typeof(InputData)) || base.CanConvert(type);
    }
    public override object ConvertStringToValue(string parameter, Type parameterType)
    {
        if (parameterType == typeof(InputData))
        {
            string[] parts = parameter.Split(',');
            return new InputData { FirstName = parts[0], LastName = parts[1] };
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ConvertStringToValue(parameter, parameterType);
        }
    }
}
public class MyWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior
{
    protected override QueryStringConverter GetQueryStringConverter(OperationDescription operationDescription)
    {
        return new MyQueryStringConverter();
    }
}
public static void Test()
{
    string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
    host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new WebHttpBinding(), "").Behaviors.Add(new MyWebHttpBehavior());
    host.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString(baseAddress + "/InsertData?param1=John,Doe"));

    client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    Console.WriteLine(client.UploadString(baseAddress + "/InsertData", "{\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\"}"));

    Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
    Console.ReadLine();
    host.Close();
 }
```

}